# How to insert text by hitting a key in chrome?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, chrome

The hotkey should be easy to disable and enable (with another shortcut).

The text and keys to enter are string, and should be called by typing "r". It should be used in a flash app for easier navigation.

Is there a chrome extension that can do it?

I've already googled and I haven't found anything.

So I need something like Auto Hotkey (https://autohotkey.com/), but for Linux.

Comment: What do you mean by "the" text? Do you just want to bind some key to the insertion of "↩"? Does it have to be "r" without modifier?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. What is `↩`? Is that supposed to represent the return key, a new line, the `↩` character itself? What is "the text"? The more details you give, the likelier it is we'll be able to help you.

Comment: It's <enter>string<enter>, and should be called by typing "r". It should be used in a flash app for easier navigation. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by use of `xbindkeys`+`xdotool`.

One has to be careful: if your string, say `my-string`, contains the letter "r", binding `xdotool type string` to `r` would cause a loop! To avoid this, I disable `xbindkeys`, then call `xdotool`, then enable `xbindkeys` back.

Suppose your string is `my-string`, you want key `F1` to enable the shortcut, and `F2` to disable it.

1. Create file `~/.xbindkeysrc` to contain:

   ```
   "killall xbindkeys && xdotool key Return type my-string && xdotool key Return && xbindkeys"
   r

   "killall xbindkeys"
   F2
   ```
2. Then use your Desktop environment's Settings manager to bind `F1` to launching `xbindkeys`.

You can now type `F1 { r | <other_keys> }... F2`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `xdotool`

Install and run xdotool it just automate keyboard/mouse/.... for you.

after installing you can this in bash:
`xdotool key Return && xdotool type sometext`

For your shortcut key you can use "gnome keyboard custom shortcuts" and assign this command to a shortkey!

> To install xdotool do: `apt-get install xdotool` (if using ubuntu)

Comment: By the way you cannot assign simple `r` for your shortcut key it must be something more complex.

Comment: After assignment of shortcut key, you should logout & log back in for changes to take effect.

Comment: Please refrain from using comments on your own questions or answers. You can easily edit your initial post and add this information, where it makes it easy to read and find.

Comment: @MelBurslan I want to keep my Answer brief and also give some advice!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly do you want to achieve but one chrome extension seems like it might be able to solve your problem (if you know javascript). It's called: *Shortkeys (Custom Keyboard Shortcuts)*

Comment: have you a link?

Comment: [here](https://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjo9ayQ8t7LAhUqCZoKHXWoDVsQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fshortkeys-custom-keyboard%2Flogpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck%3Fhl%3Den&usg=AFQjCNF9h6Q0hXBiBxF5ooUQX4Ymr6etDA&sig2=pAQq-DLDKW_-ObMmrxLSGA) you go